# How to plot each matrix in a cell with a different color in a 3D plot?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors, matlab-figure

Consider a 1x3 cell `A`:

```
A = { [A1] [A2] [A3] } 
A = {[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] [6 5 4; 9 8 7] [1 1 1]}
```

where the structure of `Ai` is such that:

```
A1 = [ 1 2 3    %coordinate (x,y,z) of point 1  
       4 5 6    %coordinate (x,y,z) of point 2  
       7 8 9 ]  %coordinate (x,y,z) of point 3 

A2 = [ 6 5 4    %coordinate (x,y,z) of point 4  
       9 8 7 ]  %coordinate (x,y,z) of point 5  

A3 = [ 1 1 1 ]  %coordinate (x,y,z) of point 6
```

How to plot all these points such that we use one color for all the points of `A1`, another color  for all the points of `A2` and some other color for all the points of `A3`?

In general, if we have a 1xn cell i.e. `A = { [A1] [A2] [A3] ... [An] }`, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate all matrices inside the cell array `A` [vertically](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/vertcat.html). Use [`jet`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/jet.html) or [any other colormap](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html#input_argument_d0e131488) to generate different colours for different matrices. Find the number of points in each matrix inside `A` to determine number of times each colour will be repeated. Generate number of copies of each colour accordingly and finally use [`scatter3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) to plot these points.

```
newA = vertcat(A{:});                    %Concatenating all matrices inside A vertically

colours = jet(numel(A));                 %Generating colours to be used
colourtimes = cellfun(@(x) size(x,1),A); %Determining num of times each colour wil be used
colourind = zeros(size(newA,1),1);       %Zero matrix with length equals num of points
colourind([1 cumsum(colourtimes(1:end-1))+1]) = 1;
colourind = cumsum(colourind);           %Linear indices of colours for newA

scatter3(newA(:,1), newA(:,2), newA(:,3),[], colours(colourind,:),'filled');
```

For the given `A`, the above code produces this result:

[image: output]